# SQL working in pma but not with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

If I run the statement within `pma` it is working perfect.

But within the script I get no error, just a `affected_rows = 0` and no updates?

Any special syntax for `mysqli`?

```
foreach ($arsubtags as &$value) {
    trim($value);
    $sql='UPDATE posts p
        INNER JOIN content c ON
        p.id_content=c.id
        AND c.ascsubid = "'.$value.'"
        SET p.ad_active="1"';
    Print($sql."<br>");
    $qry=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    Print($qry."<br><br>");
    print(mysqli_affected_rows($link));
};
```

Output is:

> UPDATE posts p INNER JOIN content c ON p.id_content=c.id AND c.ascsubid = "8e28e8" SET p.ad_active="1"
>
> 1
>
> 0